# Cannot reset root password via grub

Tags: rhel, password, root, grub

I am using Redhat Linux 5. I forgot the root password i set while installing linux OS. After rebooting right after the installation, entering root password is needed of course. So the following is what i did: I couldn't reset root password from "grub" after booting using single user mode. After writing command "passwd",instead of asking to input new unix password,it went like:

> "changing password for user root. passwd: authentication token
>   manipulation error"

It skips the following

> "Asking to input  root password.  Then it returns authentication token manipulation
>   error"

Any idea why it is doing so? This is the first time i do resetting root password via grub. The parameter i passed are "single" and "selinux=0" to disable SELINUX policy loading since it was halting when the SELINUX is not disabled.

[image]

Comment: Did you edit the boot options and add init=/bin/bash to the boot entry?

Comment: What did you do to get error “Asking to input root password. Then it returns authentication token manipulation error”

Comment: related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us type `mount` check mount options is it `rw`.

Comment: @RamanSailopal , I now tried to append the boot entry by the following:
1) init=/bin/bash
2) then pressed enter
3) at bash prompt did : mount -n -o remount,rw /
4) Tried to reset password using "passwd"
I am still getting the same error as the attach file shows above.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor
"Asking to input root password" was not the error.  After using "passwd" command , it should ask me to input the new root password.  But it didn't.  Instead, it gives "authentication token manipulation error without asking me to give root password (reset password).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the link you have sent is kinda irrelevent to my case.  In that link the member who asked was able to enter the password then he got the error.  Whereas in my case, I am not able the enter the password.  The output i am getting after writing the command "passwd" is:
"Changing password for user root."
Then it displays the error:
"authentication token manipulation error"

Why the hell it is changing the password without asking me to input it?

Comment: You didn't answer the question - is the partition mounted as rw?

Answer (score 1):

Your system is lock or mount in (ro)

1. other linux is boot
2. mount your system root mount /dev/sda /mnt (rw)
3. chroot /mnt
4. passwd root
5. reboot

Comment: What do you mean by "other linux is boot".  I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Boot your system the press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit grub;

Change the ligne:

```
ro rhgb quiet
```

to

```
 rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot

From the root shell type:

```
chroot /sysroot
```

Disable selinux

```
setenforce 0
```

To change the root password type

```
passwd root
```

Type your password twice . To change the user password:

```
passwd user
```

Update the selenux file

```
touch /.autorelabel
```

Type

```
exit
reboot
```

To update the selinux file , it will take a few minutes at:

```
relabeling could take a very long time depending on file
```

then it will reboot

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes RHEL5 and also assumes that SELINUX is not enabled.

1. At the boot loader (GRUB) menu select (highlight) the kernel you wish to boot into using the arrow keys if you have more than one kernel or OS menu item.
2. Type A to enter into append mode.
3. Press the spacebar once to add a space.
4. Type the word "single" to tell GRUB to boot into single-user.
5. Press enter and GRUB will boot you into single-user mode with root privledges.
6. Now you can successfully run the `passwd root` command.

Comment: Meh!  after doing this i am getting the issue above.  Check the attached file. I reached step 6.  Done "passwd" to reset the password , then as you can see in the attached file, it is not accepting any input from me to reset the password.  Please look at  the attached file.

Comment: @Mussa.  What attached file?

Comment: @Mussa.  At the single user prompt, please run `pwck` and `grpck`and `cat /etc/shadow | grep root` and `cat /etc/passwd | grep root` and provide output

Comment: In below comments , I am going to send you the output of each command

Comment: # pwck

user adm: directory /var/adm does not exist

user news: directroy /etc/news does not exist

user uucp: directory /var/spool/uucp does not exist


user gopher: directory /var/gopher does not exist

user ftp: directory /var/ftp does not exist

user pcap: directory /var/arpwatch does not exist

user sabayon: directory /homme/sabayon does not exist

pwck: no changes

Comment: grpck command didn't return an output

Comment: # cat /etc/shadow | grep root
cat: /etc/shadow: No such file or directory

Comment: #cat /etc/passwd | grep root
root:*:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
operator:*:11:0:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your file system is read only

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Comment: Note that the OP [tried that already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399880/cannot-reset-root-password-via-grub#comment714396_399880)